# Word-wrapping do not working with long text

Tags: flutter

Here is my widget:

```
  return Card(
      child: Container(
    height: 150,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Placeholder(
          fallbackHeight: 100,
          fallbackWidth: 100,
        ),
        Container(
          width: _deviceHeight,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 4,
              )),

              // Expanded(flex: 8, child: Text("bbb")),
              Flexible(child: Text("bbb")),
              // Flexible(child: Text("aaa")),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ));
```

I expected that text will be placed on new line, but I am getting overflow:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the second element of the `Row` with `Flexible`, like this:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Placeholder(..),
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(...
```

Inside the `Row` you need `Placeholder` to keep its width and `Container` width to be flexible.

**Edit:** And you should remove the width of the `Container`, since it would be flexible and it should take as much as possible to fit the screen.

Comment: height or width?

Comment: but what if I need column? For example I need to place few text string one after another. https://images.guru/i/1usiE I can't remove column, because without column I would not able to place "bbb..." on butom to "aaa..." string

Comment: The Column should be inside the Container, exactly like the code you posted here in the question. In that image it seems that you have another code different from the question you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your inner `Container` with an `Expanded` to provide it with the available parent constraints, otherwise the `Container` has infinite `height` and will result in an overflow (because you are on landscape).

```
 Expanded(
     child: Container(
          width: _deviceHeight,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
  ...
```

Comment: Do you sure that width should be equal to device width? I have placeholder that take same space. I did not directly as you said, but similar https://images.guru/i/1ukuc